# libGDX update and render task segregation

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to learn some simple principles of libGDX game development and got suck on the code below. I have segregated the task of update and rendering but not quite sure how to bring them together. All I am trying to do is to draw a simple rectangle that moved across the screen. My code is as below. Everything works ok except rendering.

```
package com.mygdx.gameobjects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;

public class Egg {

private Rectangle egg;

public Egg(){
    egg = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
}

public void update(float delta) {
    egg.x++;
    if (egg.x > 137) {
        egg.x = 0;
    }
}

public Rectangle getEgg() {
    return egg;
}

}
```

Update method used:

```
package com.mygdx.gameworld;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.mygdx.gameobjects.Egg;

public class GameWorld {

private Egg egg;

public GameWorld() {

    egg = new Egg();
}

public void update(float delta) {

    Gdx.app.log("GameWorld", "update");
    egg.update(delta);
}

public Egg getEgg() {
    return egg;

}
}
```

Rendering method used:

```
package com.mygdx.gameworld;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.mygdx.gameobjects.Egg;

public class GameRenderer {

private GameWorld myWorld;
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
private Egg rect;


public GameRenderer(GameWorld world) {
    myWorld = world;
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(true, 136, 204);
    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

}

public void render() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameRenderer", "render");
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);

    shapeRenderer.setColor(255 / 255.0f, 109 / 255.0f, 120 / 255.0f, 1);

    shapeRenderer.rect(myWorld.getEgg().x, myWorld.getEgg().y,
            myWorld.getEgg().width, myWorld.getEgg().height);

    shapeRenderer.end();


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the camera to the shape renderer.

Put `shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);` right before `shapeRenderer.begin`.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Not worked. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates of the eg my are within the view of the camera? That's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: The coordinates are definitely in the view of the camera. If I write the Egg class code directly in the GameWorld Class, everything works just fine. But the idea is to get the GameWorld to update only.

Comment: Maybe you can add your drawing code for GameWorld and Egg so we can see what's wrong.